# Restrict movements along an axis in LeanTouch LeanDragTranslate Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to move an AR object after it has been augmented. For this, I have used Lean touch and the script I used is LeanDragTranslate.

But now I am trying to restrict the movement along an axis so that the object never leaves the ground. How should I do this?

The script I use is

```
namespace Lean.Touch
{
    /// <summary>This component allows you to translate the current GameObject relative to the camera using the finger drag gesture.</summary>
    [HelpURL(LeanTouch.HelpUrlPrefix + "LeanDragTranslate")]
    [AddComponentMenu(LeanTouch.ComponentPathPrefix + "Drag Translate")]
    public class LeanDragTranslate : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /// <summary>The method used to find fingers to use with this component. See LeanFingerFilter documentation for more information.</summary>
        public LeanFingerFilter Use = new LeanFingerFilter(true);

        /// <summary>The camera the translation will be calculated using.\n\nNone = MainCamera.</summary>
        [Tooltip("The camera the translation will be calculated using.\n\nNone = MainCamera.")]
        public Camera Camera;

        /// <summary>If you want this component to change smoothly over time, then this allows you to control how quick the changes reach their target value.
        /// -1 = Instantly change.
        /// 1 = Slowly change.
        /// 10 = Quickly change.</summary>
        [Tooltip("If you want this component to change smoothly over time, then this allows you to control how quick the changes reach their target value.\n\n-1 = Instantly change.\n\n1 = Slowly change.\n\n10 = Quickly change.")]
        public float Dampening = -1.0f;

        [HideInInspector]
        [SerializeField]
        private Vector3 remainingTranslation;

        /// <summary>If you've set Use to ManuallyAddedFingers, then you can call this method to manually add a finger.</summary>
        public void AddFinger(LeanFinger finger)
        {
            Use.AddFinger(finger);
        }

        /// <summary>If you've set Use to ManuallyAddedFingers, then you can call this method to manually remove a finger.</summary>
        public void RemoveFinger(LeanFinger finger)
        {
            Use.RemoveFinger(finger);
        }

        /// <summary>If you've set Use to ManuallyAddedFingers, then you can call this method to manually remove all fingers.</summary>
        public void RemoveAllFingers()
        {
            Use.RemoveAllFingers();
        }
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        protected virtual void Reset()
        {
            Use.UpdateRequiredSelectable(gameObject);
        }
#endif
        protected virtual void Awake()
        {
            Use.UpdateRequiredSelectable(gameObject);
        }

        protected virtual void Update()
        {
            // Store
            var oldPosition = transform.localPosition;

            // Get the fingers we want to use
            var fingers = Use.GetFingers();

            // Calculate the screenDelta value based on these fingers
            var screenDelta = LeanGesture.GetScreenDelta(fingers);

            if (screenDelta != Vector2.zero)
            {
                // Perform the translation
                if (transform is RectTransform)
                {
                    TranslateUI(screenDelta);
                }
                else
                {
                    Translate(screenDelta);
                }
            }

            // Increment
            remainingTranslation += transform.localPosition - oldPosition;

            // Get t value
            var factor = LeanTouch.GetDampenFactor(Dampening, Time.deltaTime);

            // Dampen remainingDelta
            var newRemainingTranslation = Vector3.Lerp(remainingTranslation, Vector3.zero, factor);

            // Shift this transform by the change in delta
            transform.localPosition = oldPosition + remainingTranslation - newRemainingTranslation;

            // Update remainingDelta with the dampened value
            remainingTranslation = newRemainingTranslation;
        }

        private void TranslateUI(Vector2 screenDelta)
        {
            var camera = LeanTouch.GetCamera(Camera, gameObject);

            // Screen position of the transform
            var screenPoint = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(camera, transform.position);

            // Add the deltaPosition
            screenPoint += screenDelta;

            // Convert back to world space
            var worldPoint = default(Vector3);

            if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(transform.parent as RectTransform, screenPoint, camera, out worldPoint) == true)
            {
                transform.position = worldPoint;

            }
        }

        private void Translate(Vector2 screenDelta)
        {
            // Make sure the camera exists
            var camera = LeanTouch.GetCamera(Camera, gameObject);

            if (camera != null)
            {
                // Screen position of the transform
                var screenPoint = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

                // Add the deltaPosition
                screenPoint += (Vector3)screenDelta;

                // Convert back to world space
                transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to find camera. Either tag your camera as MainCamera, or set one in this component.", this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code I think you might need to clamp the `ScreenDelta` variable. Since `Translate` function uses ScreenDelta value.

You can do something like this:

```
ScreenDelta = new Vector3(ScreenDelta.x, Mathf.Clamp(ScreenDelta.y, 0f, 0f), ScreenDelta.y);
```

This will limit the 'y' axis to zero.

Comment: Hi, This works very well. but one thing I noticed is, it's also limiting the z-axis. Is there a workaround?

And on translating,somehow the object is getting smaller

Comment: Hey, I checked and yes it seems like there was a problem. I tried google to find out if there was any other workaround, I couldn't find it. The problem here is that we are trying to map 2D finger translation to 3D space so when you try to drag your finger upwards, you don't know if it's going upwards or backwards (you can't move fingers inside the screen of course). I'm not sure if you are using ARCore but I had to switch to ARCore Object Manipulation demo as I couldn't find any other solution too.

Answer (score 0):

In inspector Requiered Finguers count = 1

```cs
private void Translate(Vector2 screenDelta)
{
    // Make sure the camera exists
    var camera = LeanHelper.GetCamera(this._camera, gameObject);

    if (camera != null)
    {
        // Screen position of the transform
        var screenPoint = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        // Add the deltaPosition
        Vector3 Position = new Vector3(screenDelta.x, 0f, screenDelta.y/100f);
        screenPoint += (Vector3)Position * Sensitivity;

        // Convert back to world space
        transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to find camera. Either tag your camera as MainCamera, or set one in this component.", this);
    }
}
```